# Is this element Rust marks as "dead code" necessary?

Tags: rust

I'm writing an FFI wrapper to libsvm. One of the structs it uses has a `**struct{int, double}` as a member. The exact specification of this isn't important, but it's basically just a list of sparse vectors of doubles.

In my wrapper, obviously I'm allowing data to come in from the Rust side, so I have:

```
#[repr(C)]
pub struct SvmNode(pub i32, pub f64);

#[repr(C)]
struct CSvmProb {
    data: *mut *mut SvmNode
    // other fields that aren't important
}

pub struct SvmProb {
    crep: CSvmProb,
    data: Vec<Vec<SvmNode>>,
    // other fields that aren't important

    raw_data: Vec<*mut SvmNode>
}

extern "C" fn do_something(prob: *mut CSvmProb);
```

For reference, the C versions of these things look like:

```
struct svm_node {
    int index;
    double value;
};

struct svm_prob {
    struct svm_node **data; 
    // other fields that aren't important to the question
};

void do_something(svm_prob *prob);
```

The `data` member is read-only from the Rust side, it's just used for looking up stuff after you construct the problem.

The `data` field of the `SvmProb`'s `crep` is actually just `raw_data.as_ptr()`. The way it's constructed is by taking the `as_mut_ptr` from each element of `data`:

```
impl SvmProb {
    pub fn new(mut data: Vec<Vec<SvmNode>>) -> SvmProb {
        let raw_data = Vec::with_capacity(data.len());

        for v in data.iter_mut() {
            raw_data.push(v.as_mut_ptr());
        }

        // ...

        let crep = CSvmProb{ data: raw_data.as_ptr() };
        SvmProb { data: data, crep: crep }
    }
}
```

The problem is, `raw_data` is never accessed or set after `SvmProb` is constructed, the `raw_data` pointer is added to `crep` before SvmProb is constructed and yielded by the new function. So rustc/Cargo complains about `SvmProb`'s member `raw_data` being "dead code".

My question is: is this really dead code, or do I need to maintain `raw_data` for the memory to stay alive like I think I do? Alternatively, is there a way force a `Vec` to yield its raw pointer and tell it that it will no longer need to manage it when it's `drop`ped? Alternatively alternatively, is there a way without `#[allow(dead_code)]` to hint to Rust that the only reason a Vec exists is for memory keep-alive purposes?

I realize I *could* populate `CSvmNode.data` by using `heap::allocate` and a variety of other unsafe accessors, but I feel like using a Vec to manage this and then taking its pointer is safer and less error prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is: is this really dead code, or do I need to maintain raw_data for the memory to stay alive like I think I do?

Yes, you need to maintain `raw_data`, or else `crep` will be invalidated.

Do you absolutely need that `crep` field in `SvmProb`? I would instead suggest you add a `crep()` method that looks like this:

```
impl SvmProb {
    #[inline]
    fn crep(&mut self) -> CSvmProb {
        CSvmProb { data: self.raw_data.as_mut_ptr() }
    }
}
```

If you need more data to initialize a `CSvmProb` this way, you'll need to add the corresponding fields to `SvmProb` first.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I need the crep field, but I recall doing it that way for a specific reason. Like, I was pretty sure there was *something* in the library that required the CSvmProb to not die.